# useQuery in RTK not showing data despite response mapped correctly

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I'm facing a problem with mapping data get from api using RTK useQuery and mapping it into a flatlist
Now my data is correctly retrieved from server :

```typescript
export const protectedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({

  endpoints: builder => ({

   
    getdiseases: builder.query<DiseasesClient[], void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: Disease_URL,
        method: 'GET',
        //body: JSON.stringify(data),
        providesTags: ['Diseases'],
      }),
      transformResponse: (response: DiseaseForRequest[]) => mapGetDiseasesResponse(response)
    }),

.
.
.
}
```

when I `console.log(response)`, it is correctly rendered and also my `mapGetDiseasesResponse` here works correctly

```typescript
export interface DiseaseForRequest {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    schedules?: Schedule[]
}

export interface Schedule {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    specification: string
}

export interface DiseasesClient {
    id: number,
    name: string,
}

export function mapGetDiseasesResponse(response: DiseaseForRequest[]): DiseasesClient[] {
    const mappedDiseases = response.map(disease => ({
        id: disease.id,
        name: disease.name,
    }));

    return mappedDiseases;
}
```

the problem is when I try to map the data into list :

```typescript
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useGetdiseasesQuery, useGetusersQuery } from "../../../../../store/apis/protectedApi";

import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../../../../hooks/hooks";

import { CompleteProfile3 } from "./CompleteProfile3";
import { ColumnsChecked } from "../../../Interfaces/columnsChecked/ColumnsChecked.interface";
import {  Text, View } from "react-native";

import { DiseasesClient } from "../../../../../interfaces/auth/diseasesResponse.interface";


export const CompleteProfile3Container = ({ navigation, route }: any) => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetdiseasesQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching diseases:', error);
    }
  }, [error]);
  while (isLoading || isFetching) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Diseases</Text>
        <View>
          {data && data?.map((disease: DiseasesClient) => (
            <View key={disease.id}>
              <Text>{disease.name}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

data is always loading and not shown !

PS : I have seen all the solutions posted here and nothing work !

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why use `while (isLoading || isFetching) {` when an `if (isLoading || isFetching) {` would do the work? Edit: or just an `if(isFetching)` given isLoading is only significant the first time.

Comment: @govi yeah you are right, I changed if by while just to test if it gonna work...

Comment: Maybe do a `const result = useGetdiseasesQuery();` and `console.log(result)` so you always log a full result with all the `loading`, `data` values and can see those in relation to each other. That could already tell you a lot of what's happening and what you might be missing.

Comment: @phry data undefined isFetching true isLoading true isError false

Comment: That looks like it's still loading that data.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

I figured out that my problem is related to the store.
I was defining my baseQuery in a separate ts file

```html
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'apiSlice',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: builder => ({}),
    tagTypes: ["Diseases"],
});
```

and then injecting endpoints in it in another ts file :

```html
export const protectedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({

  endpoints: builder => ({
...
```

then I exported both protectedApiSlice and apiSlice in the store...

When I removed protectedApiSlice from store reducers , I got my data from getQuery.